# add-in DisplayName font size, section height changes in taskpane and dialog box

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

We are developing an add-in to encrypt and decrypt mails.

When the taskpane is opened, **DisplayName** (in manifest) content's size is fixed and we can't modify it like we do in add-in's manifest to change the taskpane **DesktopSettings** properties.

We have already checked all the documentation related to manifest and office-js but didn't see any way to handle the height of DisplayName content.

I have added the example screenshot below. Is there any way to modify the height/width/font-size of the content in the section highlighted in yellow?

[test add-in screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jGz2n.png)

Answer (score 1):

`OfficeJS` doesn't provide anything for that. There is no way to customize the caption/header of the task pane for Office web add-ins. Moreover, this area is not customizable and every client (application/host) implements its own way to display the information from the manifest.

Feature requests on Tech Community are considered, when the dev team go through the planning process. Use the github label: `Type: product feature request` at https://aka.ms/M365dev-suggestions .